# Xamarin Forms Mvvm Command no responde

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Amigos no se porque no puedo ejecutar mi command no se porque segun yo todo esta en orden, pero no cuando le doy tap al botton no pasa nada

Mi Xaml

```
 <Button Command="{Binding SubscribeCommand}" Text="Subscribe" />
```

Mi Controller

```
 public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Mi View Model

```
 public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ICommand SubscribeCommand;
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            SubscribeCommand = new Command(OnSubscribeCommand);
        }

        public void OnSubscribeCommand()
        {
            //MessagingCenter.Subscribe
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que respondan los command te estaria faltando colocarle sus metodos de acceso `get;set;`

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public ICommand SubscribeCommand {get;set;} 
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SubscribeCommand = new Command(OnSubscribeCommand);
    }

    public void OnSubscribeCommand()
    {
        //MessagingCenter.Subscribe
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuanta verdad mi querido jaquer gracias